# When should use KeyChain in Android?

Tags: android, cryptography, keychain

I have a question that what context I should use KeyChain API.

Does the KeyChain is really safety?

I know KeyChain API allows me to install a PKCS#12 key store and get 
private/public key from it for cryptography purpose.

So, if someone decompile my .apk and get the .p12 file.

They can extract private/public key from this file and decrypt my data

I hope someone can explain this for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#WhichShouldIUse)

> **Choosing Between a Keychain or the Android Keystore Provider**
>
> **Use the KeyChain API when you want system-wide credentials**. When an app requests the use of any credential through the KeyChain API, users get to choose, through a system-provided UI, which of the installed credentials an app can access. **This allows several apps to use the same set of credentials with user consent.**

The credentials can be used for digital signatures, encryption, SSL authentication or VPN

You can install a p12 file programmatically or let user install directly the file. A p12 file is password protected, so decompiling an APK which contains embedded keys will not provide direct access to them